# Find all possible primes $p$ and $q$ such that $3p^{q-1}+1$ divides $11^p+17^p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all possible primes $p$ and $q$ such that $3p^{q-1}+1$ divides $11^p+17^p$.

Please help me to solve this. Firstly I proceed with odd and even primes but I got no result. Please solve this.

Comment: One solution is $p = 3, q = 3$, because $11^p + 17^p$ is always a multiple of $28$ when $p$ and $q$ are odd, and finding solutions to $3p^{q-1} + 1 | 28$ is easier by bounding the terms.

Comment: @abcdmath: Where does the problem come from?

Comment: I don't really know who downvoted this problem. Come forward and let us know why you think it is to be downvoted. This is a very good problem.